# Recursive download of only one format with wget?

Tags: wget, download

I want to download only `jpg` files present a HTTP server. I should be able to do that with

```
wget -r -A "*.jpg" 192.168.1.2
```

but it does not download ".jpg" files. It only downloads `index.html` and then reject it:

```
2017-##-## ##:##:## (### MB/s) - ‘192.168.1.2/index.html’ saved [###/###]

Removing 192.168.1.2/index.html since it should be rejected.
```

**What is the right command to fetch all `.jpg` files in the whole server hierarchy?**

Comment: Man, I've tried this before. At the time I couldn't find an elegant solution. So I download everything and later filter my desired files with `find | xargs`.

Comment: With `-A "*.jpg"`you told wget not to download any other file, even not `index.html`. But that file is needed for the download of the rest of the files (as it includes the links). So you should extend the accept list to read `-A index.html,"*.jpg"`.